# Bet sizing with regression predicitions?

Tags: regression, kelly-criterion

Applying the kelly criterion for bet sizing is quite easy if we use a (binary) classification model (say to predict the sign of a price return) or other model where probabilities of classes are a characteristic output of the model. But if we have a regression model that outputs real values as predictions, then how do we bet size?

Say the model is a simple OLS model used to predict returns; we can get confidence intervals on output predictions. But how should we use these confidence intervals to size our bets? The model may predict a positive return, but the 90% C.I may include negative return predictions.

Comment: Practical use of Kelly for sizing will involve some modifications and/or fudging. If you have an estimate of your win rate, you could use that for the probability. Re: confidence intervals - there are papers on adjusting Kelly sizing for parameter uncertainty, e.g. Baker and McHale, 2013. Not sure if this answers your question, which I might have misunderstood.